# Schedule Data format for AutoScale

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I've got schedule data from Repeating Service. 
How can I parse the format as user friendly way?
This is the sample schedule format. 
 0 13 ? * MON *
Please let me know how I can get the definition of the schedule format.

Thank you.

```
            Repeating.Service rService = Repeating.service(client, trigger.getId());
            Repeating repeat = rService.getObjectForRepeating();

            System.out.println("repeat schedule : " + repeat.getSchedule());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the schedule attribute is in Cron Format.

**schedule attribute:**

*The cron-formatted schedule. This is run in the UTC timezone.
Required For Create
Type: 
string*

The next java script could help you.

```
/**
* This script retrieves the Repeating trigger policies for a SoftLayer_Scale_Policy, then 
* it gets the schedule attribute and parses the value (Cron format) to human readable format. 
*
* Important manual pages:
* @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Scale_Policy/getRepeatingTriggers
* @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Scale_Policy_Trigger_Repeating
*
* @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/wiki/index.php/License>
* @author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/
package SoftLayer_Java_Scripts.Examples;

import com.softlayer.api.*;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.Policy;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.policy.trigger.Repeating;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.quartz.CronExpression;

public class GetObjectScalePolicyTriggerRepeating
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
      // Fill with your valid data here.
      String user = "set me";
      String apiKey = "set me";

      long scalePolicyId = 1234;

      ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apiKey);

      Policy.Service service = Policy.service(client, scalePolicyId);

      try
      {
        List<Repeating> result = service.getRepeatingTriggers();
        for(Repeating rep : result) {
          String cronValue = rep.getSchedule();
          System.out.println("Original value: " + cronValue);
          // Fixing format in order to display the schedule. 
          String patch = "* " + cronValue;
          // Using the next library: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronExpression.html
          CronExpression cron = new CronExpression(patch);
          // Returns the next date/time after the given date/time which satisfies the cron expression.
          // (i.e. the next time it's going to be triggered)
          System.out.println("Parsed value: " + cron.getNextValidTimeAfter(new Date()));
        }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println("Script failed, review the next message for further details: " + e); 
      }
    }
}
```

The next links contain information on cron format:

http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronExpression.html

Comment: I've got a wrong data. 
<Original cron value> : 0 14 ? * MON *
<cron next valid> : Mon Jul 25 00:14:00 KST 2016   
The time is 2 PM, but "cron.getNextValidTimeAfter(new Date()));" returns 14 Minutes. Is that an issue ?

Comment: I've added the next line in the source code `String patch = "* " + cronValue;`. That line allows to see the result in an accurate way. Nevertheless you've got to have in mind that the **schedule** attribute is used for scheduling purposes and the library that I've suggested you is a 3rd party library, so you might need to read more about it in order to do further implementation.